# BLE IoT device as platform backdoor for hackers

Tags: bluetooth, iot, threats, cloud-storage

I have a IoT device that works with BLE and uses a smartphone as a bridge to connect to a digital platform (cloud).
The communication between the IoT device and the platform is based in PKI.
The IoT device has only few privileges and services to with the platform such as status communication, public key sharing and other few status messages.

If this IoT device is hacked, could it be used as a backdoor to access or change critical information in the platform?

What can a hacker do with a hacked IoT device to threat the platform data?

The hacker will not be able to access any other data than the one allowed by the platform to that device, correct?

Comment: 1. maybe, but likely not. 2. only what the platform allows a device to do anyway. 3. unless there's something wrong and hidden, yes.

Comment: Regarding the third answer, what do you mean to 'something wrong and hidden' exactly?

Comment: i mean a bug that allows capability expansion; a zero day we don't know about.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you very much for your answer.